# How to set the endorsement policy after adding a new organization

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Starting from a running network with 3 organizations, I dynamically added a new organization (org4). But now, I want to update the endorsement policy for handling the new organization, and for handling some cases, as if the machine that contains org4 breaks down, the other organizations cannot make operations in the network. I tried to make an upgrade of the smart contract with the new endorsement policy, but it doesn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Davide